# Identify Field Control properties Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, field

I have an app in which the user's actions such as "minimizing a window","closing a window","clicking a button" ... has to be captured. And those Field Controls (  like buttons, close icon , minimise icon ... ) can be in any application and have to be dynamically identified

Is there a way to do this in C# ???

Any useful pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary application? Hmmm.... tricky. I suspect that Win32 (rather than managed code) would be the way to do this - and it would be a lot of work to do properly. There are tools that do this, though - such as scripting/testing tools like Cyrano Robot a few years ago (I don't know if the product is still "alive" or not).